# Change ComboBox arrow type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a customized ComboBox in my C# WPF Window. It is my first customizing a ComboBox and I have a line of code which I have now established is the arrow on the ComboBox. However, although I have now established that the "Data" (M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z) sets the arrow on the ComboBox, I have no idea what it means or how to create a different arrow type.

```
<Path x:Name="Arrow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
```

Could someone please point me into the right direction to combine these "Data" elements to create the arrow that I require.

Comment: This is a path definition as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. Although I didn't get a definitive answer you surely put me on the right track. Upon further investigation, the weird "M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" is called "Geometry Mini Language". It is worth wile for anyone in future to have a look at the page if you need to create your own:

https://rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language/

It explains what each character means and in less than 5 minutes I had very close to what I was looking for; now I will just play with it until I have exactly what I want.

My current result is which I now just need to refine is:

```
<Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0"/>
```

I have added the explanation of the mini language for in case the link provided above stops working in time. The explanation below is by no means my own but comes from a book "Pro WPF in C# 2008" by Mathew McDonald, all credit to the author.

F value – Sets the Geometry.FillRule property. Use 0 for EvenOdd, or 1 for NonZero. This command must appear at the beginning of the string (if you decide to use it)

M x,y – Creates a new PathFigure for the geometry and sets its start point. This command must be used before any other commands except F. However, you can also use it during your drawing sequence to move the origin of your coordinate system. (The M stands for move)

L x,y – Creates a LineSegment to the specified point.

H x – Creates a horizontal LineSegment using the specified X value and keeping the Y value constant.

V y – Creates a vertical LineSegment using the specified Y value and keeping the X value constant.

A radiusx, radiusY, degrees isLargeArch, isClockwise x,y  – Creates an ArcSegment to the indicated point. You specify the radii of the ellipse that describes the arc, the number of degrees the arc is rotated, and Boolean flags that set the IsLargeArc and SweepDirection properties.

C x1,y1 x2,y2 x,y – Creates a BezierSegment to the indicated point, using control points at (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

Q x1,y1 x,y – Creates a QuadraticBezierSegment to the indicated point, with one control point at (x1, y1).

S x2,y2 x,y – Creates a smooth BezierSegment by using the second control point from the previous BezierSegment as the first control point in the new BezierSegment.

Z – Ends the current PathFigure and sets IsClosed to true. You don’t need to use this command if you don’t want to set IsClosed to true – instead, simply use M if you want to start a new PathFigure or end the string.

Answer (score 0):

See..the path over there indicates a image in vector-coordinate form.If you want to change it ..you can find such vector images on sites like www.iconfinder.com ->search for "arrow" in the search box and download any image(free version) in SVG format.
After downloading open the image in editor such as NotePad take the value of path from it and place it in your code.That's it.

You can find the icon from this link:
https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=arrow&price=free

Comment: Thanks, it seems pretty "simple", but I have tried it and find no path in the editor. Below is the image I used in SVG format.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'><svg enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" height="50px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><rect fill="none" height="50" width="50"/><polygon points="47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25 "/></svg>

Comment: Don't get confused.. Simply take the points=" " and replace the values in points with the value s in your data and will get the desired result

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. I did what you suggested but the designer shows error "Unexpected token '47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25' encountered at position 0" I have tried using integers only, removed commas and replaced with spaces, but still the same error.